# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql

Using this query:

```
select *
from
      ( Select   DISTINCT status
        From MNPdata
        where  IMSI_no = 'abc'

       )
```

I got:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Use your words, your entire question shouldn't consist exclusively of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the subquery an alias:

```
select * 
from ( 
  Select DISTINCT status From MNPdata where IMSI_no = 'abc'
) AS t
```

Since the subquery selects only `status`, you can do this instead:

```
Select DISTINCT status From MNPdata where IMSI_no = 'abc'
```